# .htaccess Exclude directory in rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to exclude URL rewriting if the directory is `mysite.com/admin`. I have tried:

```
# prepend http://www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(admin|user)($|/) - [L]
```

I'm not too familiar with this stuff, but I can't seem to get this working. Does anyone see the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the pass-through for the **admin** | **user** directories *before* the redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(admin|user)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Other than that, I don't see any rewriting going on at all, so I'm not sure what they need to be excluded from.